# Subscription of pose is not properly subscribed

Tags: ros, rxgraph, callback, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a publisher node that publishes a pose message. I have check via *rostopic echo -c /topic* and it is there the pose message. There is another node (subscriber) that subscribes to the publisher node via callback member function. The weird thing I am currently facing is the subscriber node is node able to subscribe to the message that being published. The subscriber node is not only not being able to subscribe to the message, but also, it could not send a signal that the function is ever called like below:

```
void PointCloudBuilder::poseLDCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr& poseLD_ptr)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard something");
}
```

I have also tried to publish the message in the publisher node using Pose type instead of PoseStamped and changed accordingly in the input parameter from the callback subscriber member function, however, nothing is fixed.

I am pretty sure that it is not well subscribed because I have seen the output from *rxconsole* and previously I have been doing to subscribe to pose2D type, and it was working well, and could see the correct output from *rxconsole*.

Any idea what actually went wrong with this kind of strange behavior of my subscription.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12449/subscription-of-pose-is-not-properly-subscribed/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-24**:
@joq: Thanks a lot for suggesting the right debugging way. That worked! I didn't realize that the topic name for the subscriber (a string) should match exactly the topic of interest being published.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-24**:
I think more information is needed. Does `rxgraph` show those nodes connected for this topic? Might you somehow have stopped and then restarted `roscore` sometime during the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't realize that the topic name for the subscriber (a string) has to match exactly the topic of interest being published. Previously, I thought only types of them have to be the same. When I analyze the thing in *rxgraph*, the topic of interest is never subscribed by any nodes. From there I started to think that the published and subscribed topic might have to be identical. And, after changing it, it worked. The credit should go to @joq for giving me a great hint to debug this issue.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0